# Ordinal string check

Tags: code-golf, string, number, decision-problem

## Description :

Given a string as input, check if it is a valid ordinal number in English or not. If it is valid return truthy value otherwise return falsy value. (Suggested by @Arnauld. Thanks . Also by @JoKing)

For users who want to know about *ordinal numbers* go here :

https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/cardinal-ordinal-chart.html (Suggestion by : qwr)

## Possible inputs :

```
21st ---> true
12nd ---> false
1nd ---> false
....
```

This is a **code golf** challenge so shortest code in each language will be the winner.

## Examples :

```js
console.log('12th' , true) // This evaluates to true
console.log('1st' , true) // also evaluates to true
console.log('21nd' , false) // returns false
console.log('11st' , false) // returns false
console.log('111199231923819238198231923213123909808th' , true) // true
```

Since a lot of people asked the question regarding whether input will be only valid strings or not :

All inputs will always be valid. i.e they will be in the form of string and consist of a digit (or number of digits) along with one of the four suffixes :

`st` , `nd` , `rd` , `th`

Comment: Can you clarify the rules of ordinal numbers? Or at least put a link to what the rules you are following.

Comment: They are normal rules. I changed nothing.  But thanks for the input , I added a link

Comment: @Jonathan Allan Ordinal numbers start from `1st`, negative ordinals do not exist - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309713/ordinal-form-of-negative-numbers-especially-1-2-3

Comment: @JonathanAllan OP says "Input is going to be valid ordinal pattern." which means no negatives

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: @JonathanAllan : Yes I mean that every given input will be in the format `1st` so digit along with one of the four `st` , `nd` , `rd` , `th`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan : The question has been updated

Comment: I'd recommend changing true/false values to [truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/76162) values and removing the excess part about output being a string or array (unless you actually mean input??)

Comment: @JoKing : I don't remember it being here. I will remove that. as for number 1 ok will do that too

Comment: You say the inputs will always be *valid* but I think a better term would be *well formed*. Both 12th and 12nd are *well formed* but only the former is *valid*.

Comment: When an ordinal is written we tend to see the suffix and assume it's an ordinal without checking whether that suffix is correct. I often write things like "4rd" just to see if anybody notices.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>56</s>  53 bytes

-3 thanks to  (use unique letter inclusion instead of penultimate character equality)

```python
lambda v:'hsnrhhhhhh'[(v[-4:-3]!='1')*int(v[-3])]in v
```

An unnamed function.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9hC4MgEIY/b7/CfTJHgec1yKBf0vrQaGGwWZgE@/UuUzdBH9/j7r275WPVrNGNzd29@vdj6MlWU7Vqo45D22xri7IusLs0FCi7Ttr6EHasmzTZ3DgbYp@rJbvKKKyW5oQKPXigOVBa5XELkAHAIyFSBIpYCzx9fhkpBQCj1T8CIKVA2G8VnypIAQgCJZcVj@NA8I2lGFQZBoe0QDIWvjmrz6fF@M39pjkZDzLmvg)**

#### How?

Since all input (here `v`) is guaranteed to be of the form `\d*[st|nd|rd|th]` we can just test whether a character exists in `v` which we expect to be there if it were correct (`s`, `n`, `r`, or `h`, respectively) - that is `<getExpectedLetter>in v`.

The last digit usually determines this:

```python
v[-3]: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
v[-2]: h s n r h h h h h h
```

...except when the penultimate digit is a `1`, when all should end with `th` and hence our expected character must be `h`; to evaluate this we can take a slice (to avoid an index error occurring for inputs with no -4<sup>th</sup> character) `v[-4:-3]`. Since `0` maps to `h` already we can achieve the desired effect using multiplication prior to indexing into `'hsnrhhhhhh'`.

Comment: st, nd, rd and th all have a unique letter so you can just test if it occurs in the string [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY/BDoMgDIbP21OwE7JoQqlLxMQncR5cnMFkQwNc9vRMBDYS@Pib9m@7fZxaNfq5u/vX@H5MI7EtVVYbdRzaF7av6rbC4dJRoOy6aBdCOLBh0cT6eTXEPa0juyooWEdLQoWeAtAcqJ0KuEXICOCJkCgiRaoFnj@/jJwCgMnqHwGQUiDst0lPE6UABIGSy4ancSD6plKMqo6DQ14gG4vQnLXn02bC5mHTkswHGfNf "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @AsoneTuhid nice golf - thanks!

Comment: @AsoneTuhid - also saved three on my Jelly answer, so double the thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash + GNU utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 54

Regex matching seems to be a straightforward way to go.  I'm pretty sure this expression could be shortened more:

```bash
egrep '((^|[^1])(1st|2nd|3rd)|(1.|(^|[^1])[^1-3])th)$'
```

Input from STDIN.  Output as a shell return code - 0 is truthy and 1 is falsey.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBCsIwEIXhfU7hQmiyUPJmFJKzSAtKi1mJtFnm7nFe1cD8MJPvcd9K78tzXd6Hwfup3SaMwWOrTV5z03UOzePc/j@Wk46hlnAcejfmjDlj7lKLu9ogMmCEUYvwJrsmF3oKAt0lr7CACPZyFoVN@iV9V4FCNMecYqrlAw)

Comment: What ? this is not outputting the correct answer.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman That's because it's a test suite. Take a look at the exit codes for [`1st`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzW9KLVAQV1DI64mOs4wVlPDsLikxigvpca4KEWzRsNQrwYmAyR0jWM1SzI0VdT//wcqAwA "Bash – Try It Online") and [`1th`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzW9KLVAQV1DI64mOs4wVlPDsLikxigvpca4KEWzRsNQrwYmAyR0jWM1SzI0VdT//zcsyQAA "Bash – Try It Online").

Comment: `egrep` is capable of addition and primality testing (in unary), so I think you can make this an egrep answer.

Comment: I am sorry but my bash sucks as in I have no idea about a thing in it. I got bored so used a diff checker to check for difference between input and output. I see your point. So I have one question now @Dennis : Does Bash have booleans ?

Comment: Maybe the test cases would be more clear if `egrep` would be executed separately for each input to get matching exit code for each: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLCsIwEEX3@YqhFJostJ1EoVXQD5EW1ARTKG3pQzf59zpTdeOFOZCZk3u7jn55@bpxMLirhbrt5@kIthNAkSs57u47iOL1HEFY3GNwPSRSVuFSYakkjlPQrQ1msCpI3IbfhbAxpZq8ipOFqxScILXumbZz04j/cjhAfI6E7Vq3UKegTkGdYjd5safBjIEMzTAEzTu92qxr9tlgwawmb5GALCGlKLRBmvyL/PPUaFCbIivyLKePbw "Bash – Try It Online").

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Bash is a scripting language; it has exit codes. `if egrep '((^|[^1])(1st|2nd|3rd)|(1.|(^|[^1])[^1-3])th)$'` can be used in conditionals.

Comment: I still fail to see why he is not outputting "true" or "false" instead of what he is doing. And I just checked and Bash does have booleans. so return true or false instead of deleting them. But whatever I guess this works as well. Thanks @Dennis for explanation. Would you like to answer I would like to see yours.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Please read https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages/12026#12026 and https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey

Comment: Thanks but no thanks , like I said I ain't got a clue when it comes to Bash I have already accepted this as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3):

this is under the assumption that the input is valid ordinal pattern. if its not the case changes need to be made

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),<strike>97</strike> <strike>92</strike> 78 bytes

```javascript
s=>("tsnr"[~~((n=(o=s.match(/(\d{1,2})(\D)/))[1])/10%10)-1?n%10:0]||'t')==o[2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5PC4JAEMXvfYoIwhlI3Vkva7B16VuoB/FPFrYb7tYl86uboodIejDzGH684V3TZ2qy5nK3rtJ50ZeyN/IAG2tUs4m6DkBJ0NJ4t9RmFfgQ5y/a8TdCfEIfMaIEfWJbYujSUQ2@Z0nbOtZBKXXEkz7Tyui68Gp9hhIc4rYamW0eBa5Xv9TY/5CTykdaprUpcBGdsxNdfh4UhjygYcS8xHRyCogHIQsFE1/l@g8)

#### Explanation

```javascript
s=>
   ("tsnr"                                // all the options for ordinal - 4-9 will be dealt afterwards    
      [~~(                                //floor the result of the next expression
        (n=(                              //save the number (actually just the two right digits of it into n
          o=s.match(/(\d{1,2})(\D)/))[1]) //store the number(two digits) and the postfix into o (array)
        /10%10)-1                         //if the right most(the tenths digit) is not 1 (because one is always 'th')
          ?n%10:0]                        //return n%10 (where we said 0-3 is tsnr and afterwards is th
            ||'t')                        // if the result is undefined than the request number was between 4 and 9 therefor 'th' is required
    ==o[2]                                // match it to the actual postfix
```

#### _____________________________________________________________________

port of @Herman Lauenstein

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 48 bytes

```javascript
s=>/1.th|(^|[^1])(1st|2nd|3rd|[^1-3]th)/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY69CsMwDIT3PkW32EN@ZC/24L5ISSDETtMS7GKpnfzubkIylIYeSHD6OHGP/t3jEO9PKn2wLo8mo7nUUNGUWJeuHbScAVIS3iYZ7XopZUsTrytySAx5HoLHMLtqDjc2sgIETQU3huLL8fPplyL9hwK8XenYz@j4IbpnN3r8vEhrIWEZtS@1WQEShNSNVo36Kpc/)

Comment: If the assumption reg solution can also be `***.`

Comment: If not assumed it's /\d*(st|nd|rd|th)/ input, `1sta` pass the reg test; if assumed, `/1.th|(^|[^1])(1s|2n|3r|[^1-3]t)/` work

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```java
s->s.matches(".*1.th|(.*[^1])?(1s|2n|3r|[^1-3]t).")
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZQxb4MwEIX3/IoTE44UhzOdGrXdujVLukWp5BBSSMFE@IgUFX47JTRSp4q3WDr50/np3fOd7MUuToevPims9/Rmc/c9I8qdpPXRJimtbyXRvqqK1DpKwo3Uufskr1bDRTcbDi9W8oTW5OiJer949rq0kmSpDwM9Zy1ZG@r59oN36iVk3xrXxnU71It4J0oHql/d2pybfTG0uXe7VPmBykHO/cHtjqz61bJc0nvdSHZ9HMvN1Uta6qoRfR5IKVzodBIG7CVQo8r/GeMOk0xcTzMPkk0yHCEQI5BBoBiBEOEGEW4guxG/DWK4wRyHLI8Q6Rwh2jlCxHMEqQcDAyUGiwyWGSg0DKWGodgwlBuGgsPguCd9VePSGrfRqy18OrWNkD8EMNiEIFMRTzFLMUehBxkdIvY3/pR1s67/AQ)

```java
s->  // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  s.matches(".*1.th|(.*[^1])?(1s|2n|3r|[^1-3]t).")
     //  Validates if the input matches this entire regex
```

Java's [String#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) implicitly adds `^...$`.

**Regex explanation:**

```
^.*1.th|(.*[^1])?(1s|2n|3r|[^1-3]t).$
^                                          Start of the regex
 .*1.                                       If the number ends in 11-19:
     th                                      it must have a trailing th
       |                                    If not:
        (.*    )?                            Optionally it has leading digits,
           [^1]                              excluding a 1 at the end
                 (1s|2n|3r         .      followed by either 1st, 2nd, 3rd,
                          |[^1-3]t).      0th, 4th, 5th, ..., 8th, or 9th
                                    $   End of the regex
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>35</s> 31 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @Asone Tuhid

Thanks to @Leo for finding a bug

```
1.th|(^|[^1])(1s|2n|3r|[04-9]t)
```

Outputs `1` for true and `0` for false. This assumes the input is in ordinal format with a valid suffix (ends with `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/31CvJKNGI64mOs4wVlPDsLjGKK/GuAjE1TWOLdH8/9/UrCQDAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>49</s> 60 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```
Js<2zK%J100I||qK11qK12qK13q>2z"th".?qz+J@c."dt8¸*£tÎðÎs"2J
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Js%3C2zK%25J100I%7C%7CqK11qK12qK13q%3E2z%22th%22.%3Fqz%2BJ%40c.%22dt%038%C2%B8%2a%C2%A3t%C3%8E%C2%98%C3%B0%C3%8Es%222J&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=21st%0A12nd%0A1nd%0A12th%0A1st%0A21nd%0A11st%0A111199231923819238198231923213123909808th%0A113th&debug=0)

SE ate some unprintables in the code (and in the below explanation) but they're present in the link.

Explanation:

```
Js<2zK%J100I||qK11qK12qK13q>2z"th".?qz+J@c."dt8¸*£tÎðÎs"2J # Code
Js<2z                                                         # J= the integer in the input
     K%J100                                                   # K=J%100
           I||qJ11qJ12qJ13                                    # IF K is 11, 12, or 13:
                          q>2z"th"                            #  Print whether the end of the input is "th"
                                  .?                          # Otherwise:
                                    qz                        #  Print whether the input is equal to
                                      +J                      #   J concatenated with
                                        @                   J #    The object at the Jth modular index of
                                          ."dt8¸*£tÎðÎs"   #     The string "thstndrdthththththth"
                                         c                 2  #      Chopped into strings of length 2 as a list
```

Python 3 translation:

```
z=input();J=int(z[:-2]);K=J%100
if K==11or K==12or K==13:print(z[-2:]=="th")
else:print(z==str(J)+["thstndrdthththththth"[2*i:2*i+2] for i in range(10)][J%10])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>92</s> <s>82</s> <s>74</s> 68 bytes

-8 thanks to *Chas Brown*
-6 thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```py
lambda s:(a+'t'*10+a*8)[int(s[-4:-2]):][:1]==s[-2:-1]
a='tsnr'+'t'*6
```

Constructs a big string of `th`s, `st`s, `nd`s, and `rd`s for endings `00` to `99`. Then checks to see if it matches.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>25</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-3 bytes thanks to an observation made in a comment made by  on my Python entry.

```
ḣ-2VDṫ-’Ạ×ɗ/«4ị“snrh”e
```

A monadic link.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//4bijLTJWROG5qy3igJnhuqDDl8mXL8KrNOG7i@KAnHNucmjigJ1l////MTAybmQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjsW6RmEuD3eu1n3UMPPhrgWHp5@crn9otcnD3d2PGuYU5xVlPGqYm/r/6J7D7Y@a1ngDceT//9HqhsUl6joK6kZ5KSDKuAhMmZRkgChTCGUJoQwNoLQhlDaC0sYQ2ghqhqEBjAFXCVcKU2uJEDE0tLQ0MjYEYgsoYQHhGhkaGxoZWxpYWhhAnWUIMReq1RjCM4F4wBDmEZjBRiDLYwE).

#### How?

```
ḣ-2VDṫ-’Ạ×ɗ/«4ị“snrh”e - Link: list of characters   e.g. "213rd" or "502nd" or "7th"
ḣ-2                    - head to index -2                "213"      "502"      "7"
   V                   - evaluate                         213        502        7
    D                  - cast to decimal list            [2,1,3]    [5,0,2]    [7]
     ṫ-                - tail from index -1                [1,3]      [0,2]    [7]
           /           - reduce with:                                          (no reduction since already length 1)
          ɗ            -   last 3 links as a dyad:                           
       ’               -     decrement (the left)           0         -1        x
        Ạ              -     all? (0 if 0, 1 otherwise)     0          1        x
         ×             -     multiply (by the right)        0          2        x
            «4         - minimum of that and 4              0          2        4
              ị“snrh”  - index into "snrh"                 'h'        'n'      'h'
                     e - exists in? (the input list)        0          1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 57 bytes

```perl
/..$/;say$&eq(th,st,nd,rd,(th)x6)[$_%100-$_%10-10&&$_%10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpRCsIwEET/c44YLCTpbjRS8QyeQESEFCpIWpP9qJd3zfZn5j1mlrG8I3Pvve4v9fnVZvzsabKVbE62JNukW0/dTT92COC2cgjGbHRnxkpqOIec1KGkRsfmkSaFICErolCQkEtow29e6DXnyu4aPSCwy38)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 100 bytes

```hs
f('1':_:a@[_,_])=a=="th"
f(a:b)|length b>2=f b
f(a:"th")|a>'3'=1>0
f x=elem x$words"0th 1st 2nd 3rd"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCsMgEEDRfU4hEjBCF9HshJHeoxQZUWuosUWFZpG727Tb/3kR69On1HuYmGDKKLzezMXcOSAAbZEOYUJl@ZF8frRIrJYQiP3X3@YHarYwEHoeAtnBJ7@Rffy8iqt0PoGojcjsyFIc7RuuGd5lzW0MVJ68fwE)

Comment: 90 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCoMwFET3/YrbS8GIFjS2GzH9gnbVpZVygwZLfZGkuPHf06ibmeEcmJbMt@k65xQL0iB/55SXshKqDJIgplhWB8Uol@EiCyQUCuSSFpmQQrB51LVB24KxMNSga4wi3UwNWQ8xPB51Q3VJlevpM4CAnqYHsJeB8w2mn31afR/gBAaiCHCFuC7TjjNTYMLQuxITfxVj4s9jTI1dcyN8WAnfeLbnbvmmU57tnfHL1a/K/QE "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org), 56 bytes

```
s="1nd"
b=Ordinal(FromBase(Take(s,1,Length(s)-2),10))==s
```

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/s98dehwu)

Input is `s`, Output is `b`. `b` is `true` if `s` is a valid ordinal, `false` otherwise.

I just realized that GeoGebra has string support, so I had to try it.

#### Explanation:

```
Ordinal(FromBase(Take(s,1,Length(s)-2),10))==s
                 Take(s,1,Length(s)-2)                s without the last two characters
        FromBase(                     ,10)            Convert the string to a number
Ordinal(                                  )           Convert the number to ordinal form
                                           ==s        Is it equal to s?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
₌Ǎ⌊∆o$c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigozHjeKMiuKIhm8kYyIsIiIsIjIxbmQiXQ==)

Because we have a built-in for that.

### Explained

```
₌Ǎ⌊∆o$c
₌Ǎ⌊     # Push the letters and numbers of the input
∆o      # Push the corresponding ordinal string
$c      # are the letters of the string contained in the ordinal string?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.text.english`, 37 bytes

```
[ 2 cut* swap dec> ordinal-suffix = ]
```

[image]

### Explanation

```
                ! "121th"
2 cut*          ! "121" "th"
swap            ! "th" "121"
dec>            ! "th" 121
ordinal-suffix  ! "th" "st"
=               ! f
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 51 bytes

Port of [@Kevin Cruijssen's Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162378/110802) in Scala.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZIxT8MwEIX3/IpTJrsSrs9hqpQiGNiYYENFMqnVFBknig8EIvz2EAkWlJfx3nBP33eXGx/91D2/hEbozp8ThQ8J6Zjpuu/pqyB695GanbqX4ZxO9f6m62LwSVNNU6732bx6adqQVWk2bKQdldk8PvFBXynOo0tjNYzzfFEdRJtST/PG7ZYehjdpP3fz0M9rJSbVqJKzlFr/z1w6LrJqWGaX0i4ytihkFDoUVihERQ4VOYiDeBwCcpgIIllUxRZ1sUVlbGHbikBoECvEDqFEhhYZamTokaFIXtEDOHTx@523Puaw@E50Y5BhYgiBGDACJoALeE0CvuXf5u9i@gE)

```scala
s=>s.matches(".*1.th|(.*[^1])?(1s|2n|3r|[^1-3]t).")
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>94</s> <s>82</s> <s>77</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```python
lambda s:'tsnrthtddh'[min(4,int(s[-3])*(('0'+s)[-4]!='1'))::5]==s[-2:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BDoMgFETX7Sno6kOriR9sIiSchLKwIUaTigb@pqe3tsXFzGTyZjHrm8Ylym2wj@3Vz8/Qs2yAckw0UggjuHmKvK2mSDy7Wnlx5RwauGXh6tZfLCAIYczdW7tzafw2LIkRmyJzgJmgYiBj@AZKGn@1JBaMzTFAVYjEY4KotVS4qyvW/atEhVLpRneNSgG8OZ/WtN9kVLGBk9g04gc)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 24 bytes

```
0ìþR2£`≠*.•’‘vê₅ù•sèsáнQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv8wNWFiMWX//zDDrMO@UjLCo2DiiaAqLuKAouKAmeKAmHbDquKChcO54oCic8Ooc8Oh0L1R//8xc3Q)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVln53@DwmsP7gowOLU541LlAS@9Rw6JHDTMfNcwoO7zqUVPr4Z1AgeLDK4oPL7ywN/B/pdLh/Qq6dgqH9yvp/DcoyeAyLC7hMspL4TIFsQ1BhBGQMAILGxelcBkagEhTIDYCChmCxA2KUgA)

**Explanation**

```
0ì                         # prepend 0 to input
  þ                        # remove letters
   R                       # reverse
    2£                     # take the first 2 digits
      `≠                   # check if the 2nd digit is false
        *                  # and multiply with the 1st digit
         .•’‘vê₅ù•         # push the string "tsnrtttttt"
                  sè       # index into this string with the number calculated
                    sáн    # get the first letter of the input
                       Q   # compare for equality
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>42</s> 39 bytes

Lambda:

```ruby
->s{s*2=~/1..h|[^1](1s|2n|3r|[4-90]t)/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BDoIwEETP9is2cEANIFs8UBP1Q2pNVIqQmEJoSTQUfx1BTNTD7mZmXzJTN@dHn237YKdbvaTb5wrDMLf8iGKO2lJl49rydcAiYRarrq8ao8Ep1HAh2MG1NGBB3it5MTI9qINyCOGEe0hN7vlg6kYKf9TaePCjKap0@Genm/4AI/FvIDJGYxwm@axkkhRjpDGLWBIl3xgiQnm65JCWYAsfSktmU1u3LbqxrNtmvBCwf@OwmbK6ob/blp1DpEr7Fw)

User input:

```ruby
p gets*2=~/1..h|[^1](1s|2n|3r|[4-90]t)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhPbWkWMvItk7fUE8voyY6zjBWw7C4xiivxrioJtpE19IgtkRT//9/Q6O8FAA)

Matches:

- `1(anything)(anything)h` - `12th`
- `(not 1)1s` - (`1st`)
- `(not 1)2n` - (`2nd`)
- `(not 1)3r` - (`3rd`)

Because `[^1]` (`not 1`) doesn't match the beginning of a string, the input is duplicated to make sure there's a character before the last.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 35 bytes

```ruby
p~/1..h|([^1]|^)(1s|2n|3r|[4-90]t)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6BO31BPL6NGIzrOMLYmTlPDsLjGKK/GuKgm2kTX0iC2RFP//39Do7yUf/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA)

Same idea as above but instead of duplicating the string, this also matches the start of the string (`^`).

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 63 bytes

```
=A1&MID("thstndrdth",MIN(9,2*RIGHT(A1)*(MOD(A1-11,100)>2)+1),2)
```

---

`(MOD(A1-11,100)>2)` returns `FALSE` when `A1` ends with `11`-`13`

`2*RIGHT(A1)*(MOD(A1-11,100)>2)+1` returns `1` if it's in `11`-`13` and `3`,`5`,`7`,etc. otherwise

`MIN(9,~)` changes any returns above `9` into `9` to pull the `th` from the string

`MID("thstndrdth",MIN(~),2)` pulls out the first `th` for inputs ending in `11`-`13`, `st` for `1`, `nd` for `2`, `rd` for `3`, and the last `th` for anything higher.

`=A1&MID(~)` prepends the original number to the ordinal.

---

<sub><sub>Posting as wiki since I am not the author of this. ([Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.excel.misc/0-k9uq9cEGQ/fDcZc-2OugoJ))</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 122 bytes

Unlike most of the other answers on here, this will actually return false when the input is not a "valid ordinal pattern", so it will correctly return false on input like "3a23rd", "monkey" or "╚§+!".  So I think this works for the entire set of possible input strings.

```
StringMatchQ[((d=DigitCharacter)...~~"1"~(e=Except)~d~~(e["1"|"2"|"3",d]~~"th")|("1st"|"2nd"|"3rd"))|(d...~~"1"~~d~~"th")]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU29CoNADH6XTApiTeygg1BoOxZaOorD4flzg1Y0Q6H2Xt3GUxpIwveXdIrbqlNsSrXU2fLk0fTNTXHZPnLP09nFNIbPrRpVydXoh2FoLSBYr8qu77Ia2LfaCsqFnIGkYwh0ISZuwZ89wIlXoderNGrwhdT/M2vYOYvlLp85rw@nD6BUmlKM0sk@kg0SxkhxGqVJlEguAEI5vS75E4B@NTKRnITkJIW4wWhfzkk0DS6njkJ/i@UH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>65</s> 59 bytes

```
SpokenString@p[[#]]~StringTake~{5,-14}&@@ToExpression@#==#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8T@4ID87NS@4pCgzL92hIDpaOTa2DsILScxOras21dE1NKlVc3AIyXetKChKLS7OzM9zULa1VVb7r8kVAFRY4pDmoGRoZFhcooTCL0pB5huiyRsalmQo/QcA)

Of course Mathematica has a built-in (although undocumented) for converting to ordinal number. [Source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64860/built-in-way-to-convert-integer-to-ordinal-string).

(for the 65-byte version: according to that it seems that v9 and before doesn't need calling `Speak` before so it may be possible to save some more bytes)

Also check out KellyLowder's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162954) for a non-builtin version.

Answer (score 0):

## PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expression), 29 bytes

```
1.th|(?<!1)(1s|2n|3r)|[4-90]t
```

We accept `th` after any "teen" number, or after any digit other than 1..3.  For 1..3, we use a negative lookbehind to accept `st`, `nd`, or `rd` only when not preceded by `1`.

### Test program

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

ok=(✓ ❌)

for i
do grep -Pq '1.th|(?<!1)(1s|2n|3r)|[4-90]t' <<<"$i"; echo $i ${ok[$?]}
done
```

#### Results

```
1st ✓
1th ❌
2nd ✓
2th ❌
3rd ✓
3th ❌
4st ❌
4th ✓
11th ✓
11st ❌
12nd ❌
12th ✓
13th ✓
13rd ❌
112nd ❌
112th ✓
21nd ❌
32nd ✓
33rd ✓
21th ❌
21st ✓
11st ❌
111199231923819238198231923213123909808th ✓
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code, 65 bytes

```
00000000: 31c0 4180 3930 7cfa 8079 0161 7ef4 8079  1.A.90|..y.a~..y
00000010: ff31 7418 31db 8a19 83eb 308a 9300 0000  .1t.1.....0.....
00000020: 0031 db43 3851 010f 44c3 eb0a 31db 4380  .1.C8Q..D...1.C.
00000030: 7901 740f 44c3 c374 736e 7274 7474 7474  y.t.D..tsnrttttt
00000040: 74                                       t
```

Assembly:

```
section .text
	global func
func:					;the function uses fastcall conventions
					;ecx=first arg to function (ptr to input string)
	xor eax, eax			;reset eax to 0
	read_str:
		inc ecx			;increment ptr to string

		cmp byte [ecx], '0'
		jl read_str		;if the char isn't a digit, get next digit
		cmp byte [ecx+1], 'a'
		jle read_str		;if the char after the digit isn't a letter, get next digit
		cmp byte [ecx-1], '1'
		je tens 		;10-19 have different rules, so jump to 'tens'
		xor ebx, ebx		;reset ebx to 0
		mov bl, byte [ecx]  	;get current digit and store in bl (low byte of ebx)
		sub ebx, 0x30		;convert ascii digit to number
		mov dl, [lookup_table+ebx] ;get correct ordinal from lookup table
		xor ebx, ebx		;reset ebx to 0
		inc ebx			;set ebx to 1
		cmp byte [ecx+1], dl	;is the ordinal correct according to the lookup table?
		cmove eax, ebx		;if the ordinal is valid, set eax (return reg) to 1 (in ebx)
		jmp end			;jump to the end of the function and return

		tens:
		xor ebx, ebx		;reset ebx to 0
		inc ebx			;set ebx to 1
		cmp byte [ecx+1], 't'	;does it end in th?
		cmove eax, ebx		;if the ordinal is valid, set eax (return reg) to 1 (in ebx)

	end:
	ret				;return the value in eax
section .data
	lookup_table db 'tsnrtttttt'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZtb@JGEP5s/4oRusgmwcQ2VxXw5SpVvarf7gcEhNbrNThn76LdNXGV8tvTmTUmEN2p/XBIMfvyzDMzz8yY5MzsXjmz8OnTl69/wme4t83@nk2ZaSADSV9RKepyll7eRKrfcVWIqUKg4DsFI190VmgJlbSw2TBrdZW3Vmw2YVgyYzmr6/EYylbykO@Yvh1n4DeskuH4xXcHVhhrHtcPLyt/NUoTY1ejCa6SVBan1XmR2t1pdUZdrJJksUhnCf7NT495v02TWZLOFvFiHs8Hhvl59UsyrNKzy/lMDz7fVnGPi/1j5pdKh5Rx9RBnfQLVOqvu7jCpvcaLMlyNbswSboqVRKMBMnE6DLvxOPOP/nE0VMDYNp/yDHXwt5xfC47luARdlSKSKtpXAqJmljprlT8VbbOH6I8rHLopxAEZCqH1NdBcAf8BK8QlGE@2WiDuCwSPcbRYv3w8QoCnvLUQ5fBr9DElKw1RAcFKBm8bB3N05GAnuqntLB49Y4Icv9nzNwhenGjwIblPj4TvNYTRSt7e3v7@txXAVSvtEncreWNWcgQfQurgaPydrFxjRuJk/pfoKEeyRaUvsdB1BUQY5v59cHTx@T2trRpxXZFXI7itlISpxSnwvW2tcla7ZvfpsfTok9mdcGcO2hphYJgMTEsehKQL4/dgwbuHstLGAtNbsOrNMtyjpHhQyT2qbnDQ5Hbse53SIFg3oQcRaGGEpQ1hY9/TghUbRC/RQSU5jq2D4VKLBn3DibYn9BHFsSNyEv0RsesJBHGAp081DFRkXgKlRRMMlZEBhgtFta3sBLboXqIe/f49311CjKxnFD@iZCW@VNzWkZxd1MLixX/5iJyPxPkQ2HzSAPIncZQsYMcORFqWQlPyuq2FmYBR8ESDgDoEhCdTJ2xOwubdm675oKvXqAPk9eRCKgAvo8h4qx15HzuTBYqrtMDKoQGEtXrujVRJfFhDz7R57yvuZjE6c32h0dbwqjrxoFvZNrnQJ98F@n6slfrW7jeW5bW4Q4Y19BEojIBbULqoJLWkVg30WHDY/5Gfa5bcNcvFTfLdghY11s@4gg0uhxAY5@7INTMBLsP4zbEpLEnfwi6SUyMMRMh7YHVVYJVOjR1qYVv8zdFiO3YxAb6MBymfMDghCwp7KCmx4RHpfTWLVJmeitqe6r78yboENvCyQuHIYwEpBIzT7n561r6H3Euadev17wCHJD4kaV3nIYV/fl8VzDLfu2weKHKM1kht3Sd4xX8NXv8F)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 60 bytes

boring: regexp once more the shortest solution

```php
<?=preg_match("/([^1]|^)(1st|2nd|3rd|\dth)$|1\dth$/",$argn);
```

empty output for falsy, `1` for truthy.

Run as pipe with `-nF` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eeb131319f5734a74a0654e85ed3d3ea7f3b2a6b). (TiO wrapped as function for convenience)